# Launch a tab with Actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a activity **Main** which extends from SherlockFragmentActivity. In this activity **Main**, I have 3 tabs(Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3), they extend from SherlockFragment.

Now, How to launch **Main's** the **Tab3** when I click at a button from other activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some extra params in the intent you are using to start the activity **Main**. You can do something like `intent.putExtra(key,value)`, and after that in the **Main** activity inside `onCreate()` you can do `getIntent.getExtras()` and you will be able to start whatever fragment you want

Answer (score 0):

In first activity

```
intent.putExtra("tabs", 2);
```

In activity with tab:

```
int tab_index = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("tab",0);
tabs.setCurrentTab(tab_index);
```